# Is there a way to use (:any) but not actually charter?

Tags: codeigniter, url, any, cyrillic

I have a problem with codeigniter and cyrilc url I'm trying to do something like this,

site.com/home
site.com/начало

in my router I've got

```
$route['([А-Яа-яa-zA-Z0-9-]+)'] = "home/index/$1";
```

Which dosn't work I put in my config.php and

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-zа-яё 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

but still dosn't work then I found in internet

```
$route['(:any+)(?:(.html))?'] = "home/page/$1";
```

Which is working but, now I lose my router native behavior because :any gives and /

so Is there a way to use (:any) but not actually any, so I can keep my router behavior

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you clarify: "because :any gives and /" - You mean that just "home/index/" works, but you don't want this to, only if there is a value?

Comment: you still need to post at least an example or explain as `jmadsen` mentioned

Comment: Sorry, I want all pages to go on home/page/$1 how is now, but I want to keep and home/foo/bar, controller/action, without put each in router list, so something as any charter except / and then should work. Sorry if my explanation is not very good, is because my English